# SQLite plugin for Phonegap?

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, windows-8.1, phonegap

I have a Phonegap project which so far has been used to build an Android app. I'm using locally installed Phonegap on Windows with a pre-populated SQLite database. The project uses Cordova-sqlite-ext plugin, my version is about a year old, have not had need to update.

Now I need to build a Windows version which should run also on Windows 8.1, not only Windows 10. This is for real computers, phones are not that important. It seems that in a few months also an iOS version may be needed.

After checking Cordova-sqlite-storage, Cordova-sqlite-ext, Cordova-sqlite-evcore-extbuild-free and Cordova-sqlite-legacy-build-support at GitHub I'm lost and don't know can I use any to reach all my goals.

1. Switching from Phonegap to Cordova is not an option because
   building an iOS app on Windows is not possible with Cordova,
   right?
2. PhoneGap CLI and Build are supported only by
   evcore-extbuild-free which does not support pre-populated
   databases.
3. Building for Windows 8.1 requires the legacy one
   which does not support pre-populated databases.

So my question is that has anyone tried something like that? I'm wishing the documentation might not be up-to-date but perhaps that's a long shot. If nothing else I might be able to create the database structure and then ask a user to download data to populate it, but would prefer to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to develop the app using Windows and build the iOS version on a Mac. You could buy a single Mac to use as a build server or use a service like MacInCloud. If you're using Visual Studio, there are [instructions](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ios/) for setting this up.